# Four specific questions regarding this htaccess file

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

```
#+FollowSymLinks must be enabled for any rules to work, this is a security 
#requirement of the rewrite engine. Normally it's enabled in the root and you 
#shouldn't have to add it, but it doesn't hurt to do so.
Options +FollowSymlinks
#Apache scans all incoming URL requests, checks for matches in our .htaccess file 
#and rewrites those matching URLs to whatever we specify.
#to enable runtime rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

#this tells mod_rewrite to leave the URL unchanged (the dash part -) and quit 
#other rewwrite processing rules if the requested segment has one of those 
#prefixes (that's what we asking when we use the ^ sign), on the list. If the 
#prefix is in the list, all subsequent Rewrite Rules are skipped.
#So to avoid some files OR directories to be redirected we use:
RewriteRule ^(somefile|somedir|someotherfile) – [L]
```

**1) Don't we need a condition here before these previous RewriteRule ?**

```
#this will allow direct linkage to this extensions, regardless the case sensitive.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|ico|zip|rar|mov|mpeg4|mp4|gif|jpg|png|css|doc|pdf|docx|wmv|mpeg|avi|mpg|flv|ppt|pptx|txt)$ - [NC]
```

**2) Will the [NC] flag deal with all case variations here?**

```
#if the request uri has not public...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
#rewrite to public something...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

**3) Why do we have $1 and not /public/index.php on our RewriteRule?**

```
#rewrite all requests that start with public, to public/index.php and if that's 
#the case, don't run any other rule.
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

**4) since this is the last rule, can we remove the L flag ?**

Comment: For questions 1, 2 and 4 a Yes or No may suffice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, anything that starts with `somefile`, `somedir` or `someotherfile` will not be rewritten (`-`). `[L]` ensures that further rules (including this one) will not be processed.
2. Yes.
3. Because the `RewriteCond` can match `/public/otherthing` as well, not just `/public/index.php`.
4. No, without `[L]`, an infinite loop will occur because the rewritten URL `/public/index.php` matches `` `^public.*$ ``.

Comment: can I ask your opinion about if this .htaccess file has some serious issues that I need to consider? Or is there any standard way of doing the above that I may not be aware of? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Add `[L]` to your rule regarding static files, those URL's do not have to be rewritten. `RewriteRule pattern -` just means "Keep the current URL, looking for further rules". With `[L]` appended, it means "Keep the current URL and do not search for further rewrites".